# How to save textbox text to notepad and save again a textbox text to add it into the same note pad?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, save, notepad, save-as

I want to save my textbox1.text in a notepad of my computer. And after saving that, I will save the next textbox1.text again. But I want it to be added to the same notepad. Anyone can help me on the code? Using VB net.

I have a one form with controls and all entries will be displayed on one textbox. I want to save that textbox but I don't know how.

Comment: For the record, your not saving "to notepad" or "to a notepad". You're saving to a text file. Notepad is a text editor, i.e. an app that edits text files. There are many other text editors available too, other than the one Microsoft provides with Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-7.0) method to save the text to a file:

```
Public Sub SaveTextToFile(FilePath As String, Text As String)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, Text)
End Sub
```

Here is an example of using the method:

```
SaveTextToFile("C:\New.txt", textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Can you show me where in my code I'm going to place that?
Inside class or outside or?

Comment: It should be placed inside of your class.

Comment: I see.

So, that will be like this.


`Public class Form1
Public Sub SaveTextToFile(FilePath As String, Text As String)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, Text)
End Sub


End class`

And now, where will I place the 
`SaveTextToFile("C:\New.txt", textBox1.Text)`


With the form I have, will I be able to choose a path where to save the text file(note pad) and rename the txt file and if possible, can I create new txt file for another save?

Comment: You can have as many files as you want, all you have to do is change the filepath in your code.

Comment: Ahh okay. So, it can only be done in my code. If I want to do that outside the ode, what control will I be using. I will add label "Choose save path:" and "File name: " Then beside it is what control?

Comment: I would recommend using a [Textbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Comment: Thank you. I know now how it works now.

But do you know how can I create file without inputing the path address in a textbox or in a code?
What I mean is when I click a button, it will open a document folder then, from there, I will create or choose a txt file where I want to save my textbox.text

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about this issue :)

Comment: Yes I've posted again :)